# select distinct values from json arrays in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have table like this
my_table

```
id    my_json
1     ['1','2','3']
2     ['2']
3     ['2','3']
...
12000 ....
```

I want to find all distinct values in json's arrays
like this
result
'1'
'2'
'3'

I have this code but i need split values to rows

```
set @items = (SELECT 
     GROUP_CONCAT(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(lower(my_json), ']', ''), '[', '')
        SEPARATOR ','
    )
FROM my_table);
SELECT CONCAT ('[',@items,']') AS jarray;

result is
[1,2,3]
```

probably somebody have ideas?

Comment: Use the `JSON_TABLE()` function to convert elements of a JSON array to separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_table`:

```
select json_arrayagg(t2.v) from (select distinct t1.v from tbl t 
  cross join json_table(t.my_json, '$[*]' columns( v int path '$')) t1) t2
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91e26a27a1ab91f39a4da25a30a3aadf).